# What is this Text Styles thing in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

Wondering if there is some way to modify the properties found in this Text Styles dropdown on interface builder. Not sure how to find any docs relating to this.

[image]

Comment: To whomever -1'ed this question.

1. Why? What was it violating
2. You know this is why SO has a poor reputation, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Text Styles**

Text Styles are semantic descriptions.

There are a fixed number of descriptions, and currently, in iOS 9,

10 styles are supported:
Title1, Title2, Title3
Headline, Subheadline
Body
Footnote
Caption1, Caption2
Callout

Use this link for reference
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uifontdescriptor#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Text_Styles